# Docker service suddenly stopped responding

Tags: docker, ubuntu

`systemctl restart|start docker` or `docker version` or `docker *` any call to docker service is not responding. I also tried removing and reinstalling docker. `systemctl status docker` returns

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Fri 2020-05-08 00:41:01 +0545; 8min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 7311 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 16
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─7311 /usr/bin/dockerd --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

मे 08 00:41:01 n10976 dockerd[7311]: time="2020-05-08T00:41:01.148154755+05:45" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
मे 08 00:41:01 n10976 dockerd[7311]: time="2020-05-08T00:41:01.148174124+05:45" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
मे 08 00:41:01 n10976 dockerd[7311]: time="2020-05-08T00:41:01.150556313+05:45" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
मे 08 00:41:01 n10976 dockerd[7311]: time="2020-05-08T00:41:01.165219552+05:45" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
मे 08 00:41:01 n10976 dockerd[7311]: time="2020-05-08T00:41:01.165243010+05:45" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
मे 08 00:41:01 n10976 dockerd[7311]: time="2020-05-08T00:41:01.165255465+05:45" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight"
मे 08 00:41:01 n10976 dockerd[7311]: time="2020-05-08T00:41:01.165264418+05:45" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device"
मे 08 00:41:01 n10976 dockerd[7311]: time="2020-05-08T00:41:01.165454194+05:45" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
मे 08 00:41:01 n10976 dockerd[7311]: time="2020-05-08T00:41:01.249268695+05:45" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
मे 08 00:41:01 n10976 dockerd[7311]: time="2020-05-08T00:41:01.283872430+05:45" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
```

uname -a

```
Linux n10976 5.3.0-52-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 30 16:13:51 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Linux kernel 5.3.0-52-generic has some issue. so i switched back to Kernel 5.3.0-47-generic. and now its working as earlier.